# What is the "N" before a string argument

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

While reading SQL Server documentation I came across the following statement:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
   @server=N'S1_instance1', 
   @srvproduct=N'',
   @provider=N'SQLNCLI', 
   @datasrc=N'S1\instance1';
```

What is the "N" before the string arguments? It seems to be optional as, without them, the statement works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239530/en-au)

> The "N" prefix stands for National Language in the SQL-92 standard,
>   and must be uppercase. If you do not prefix a Unicode string constant
>   with N, SQL Server will convert it to the non-Unicode code page of the
>   current database before it uses the string.

Some more information from stack exchange is [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12475/n-prefix-before-string-in-transact-sql-query)

Comment: The other Stack Overflow answer as a very good link explaining it: http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It indicates that the string is an [`NVARCHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx), as opposed to `VARCHAR`.